# Not able to resolve javax.validation.constraints.Email; package

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, annotations

Belo is my whole Entity class code.

[image]

```
package com.email.esp.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Transient;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users", uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "email" }) })
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 30)
    private String name;

    @Email(message = "Email is not valid", regexp = "(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|\"(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21\\x23-\\x5b\\x5d-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])*\")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\\x01-\\x08\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x1f\\x21-\\x5a\\x53-\\x7f]|\\\\[\\x01-\\x09\\x0b\\x0c\\x0e-\\x7f])+)\\])")
    @NotEmpty(message = "Email cannot be empty")
    private String email;

    @Transient // meaning it will not be saved in DB
    //@Size(min = 5, max = 15, message = "{register.password.size}")
    private String plainPassword; // unencrytped

    @Transient
    private String repeatPassword;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String phone;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 500)
    private String about;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String profilePic;
    
    @Column(name="enabled")
    private Boolean enabled = true;

}
```

I'm trying to use the spring Email core package in my spring boot project. I have added the dependency in my pom file but for some weird reason the import statement for import javax.validation.constraints.Email; is not getting resolved. Any idea why is this happening?? Here is the dependency , i have ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.9-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.email</groupId>
    <artifactId>esp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>esp</name>
    <description>Email Service Provider Using Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
          
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

`javax.validation.constraints.Email` annotation depends on Jakarta Bean Validation providers for validation.

You could try to add `spring-boot-starter-validation` dependency to your pom.xml. This dependency contains all the required dependencies (including jakarta and hibernate-validator which is a compliant validator for this)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```